# How to make sure Spark master node is using the worker nodes? (Google cluster)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing, spark-submit

I just created a Google Cloud cluster (1 master and 6 workers) and by default Spark is configured.

I have a pure python code that uses NLTK to build the dependency tree for each line from a text file. When I run this code on the master `spark-submit run.py` I get the same execution time when I run it using my machine.

How to make sure that the master is using the workers in order to reduce the execution time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the spark UI. If its running on top of yarn, please open the yarn UI and click on your application id which will open the spark UI. Check under the executors tab it will have the node ip address also.

could you please share your spark submit config.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Is there a command for that? It is a long process to do that without a UI since I am connecting using `ssh`

Comment: The spark UI should be present. Can you check your spark log

Answer (score 0):

Your command 'spark-submit run.py' doesn't seem to send your job to YARN. To do such thing, you need to add the --master parameter. For example, a valid command to execute a job in YARN is:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master yarn python/pi.py 1000
```

If you execute your job from the master, this execution will be straightforward. Anyway, check [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) for another parameter that spark-submit accept.

For a Dataproc cluster (Hadoop Google cluster) you have two options to check the job history including the ones that are running:

- By command line from the master: yarn application -list, this option sometimes needs additional configuration. If you have troubles, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836740/yarn-application-list-doesnt-show-any-results) will be useful.
- By UI. Dataproc enables you to access the Spark Web UI, it improves monitoring tasks. Check [this link](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces) to learn how to access the Spark UI and other Dataproc UIs. In summary, you have to create a tunnel and configure your browser to use socks proxy.

Hope the information above help you.

Comment: But if `spark-env.sh` is configured correctly, the master should be picked up from there. Also, there isn't much reason to run master other than Spark Standalone if Spark is sourcing data from GCS

Comment: We don't have information on modifications in the spark-env.sh script. Most likely, our colleague didn't modify such file as he didn't mention it. On the other hand, he/she is asking on Google cluster, so he is using Dataproc instead of Standalone cluster. There is a strong relation between Dataproc and GCS , however he uses NL instead. Let's see if more information is attached.